# Problem using keras for neural network for two outputs

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm using Keras with python and I'm facing a problem, when running the code below, I usually get two accuracy results, 10% or 90%

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
ler = loadtxt(r'C:\Users\Mateus\Desktop\Nova\artigo.csv')
ler_norm = ler / np.sqrt(np.sum(ler**2))
entrada = ler_norm[:,0:3]
saida = ler[:,3:5]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 3, input_dim = 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(entrada, saida, epochs=100, batch_size=10)
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(entrada, saida)
print('Accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(accuracy*100))
```

A portion of values used in "entrada" e "saida" (The original database has 300x5):

```
68|541|257|72.9|84.0
102|576|322|73.6|84.8
54|528|315|73.6|84.0
99|435|357|73.7|84.0
95|454|115|73.1|83.5
91|300|140|73.5|82.5
118|362|144|73.6|85.0
118|450|233|73.4|83.5
93|378|121|73.7|84.0
95|403|117|73.3|84.0
131|349|80|73.4|85.0
112|467|257|74.0|83.5
50|463|134|73.2|83.5
97|374|159|73.3|85.0
```

The last 15 epochs:

```
Epoch 85/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 177us/step - loss: 77.1145 - acc: 0.4867
Epoch 86/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 167us/step - loss: 77.1126 - acc: 0.5400
Epoch 87/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 157us/step - loss: 77.1108 - acc: 0.5600
Epoch 88/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 159us/step - loss: 77.1091 - acc: 0.6200
Epoch 89/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 167us/step - loss: 77.1073 - acc: 0.6733
Epoch 90/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 171us/step - loss: 77.1057 - acc: 0.5333
Epoch 91/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 157us/step - loss: 77.1040 - acc: 0.4600
Epoch 92/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 164us/step - loss: 77.1024 - acc: 0.5333
Epoch 93/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 176us/step - loss: 77.1008 - acc: 0.4800
Epoch 94/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 160us/step - loss: 77.0992 - acc: 0.5400
Epoch 95/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 150us/step - loss: 77.0977 - acc: 0.6067
Epoch 96/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 166us/step - loss: 77.0962 - acc: 0.5133
Epoch 97/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 168us/step - loss: 77.0947 - acc: 0.5400
Epoch 98/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 150us/step - loss: 77.0933 - acc: 0.4067
Epoch 99/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 164us/step - loss: 77.0919 - acc: 0.5267
Epoch 100/100
300/300 [==============================] - 0s 166us/step - loss: 77.0905 - acc: 0.5067
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?
Thanks for listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to predict a continuous value that is around 80 with a `Sigmoid` activation which will gives you outputs between 0 and 1.
Try using linear or relu activations :

```
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear'))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'relu'))
```

Moreover using `accuracy` in a regression problem have no sense, try changing your metric with something like `mae`.

```
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])
```

Comment: Thanks, Thibault. You're right, I forgot about that (using accuracy metrics in a regression). I tried change the sigmoid to 'relu' or 'linear', changed metrics to 'mae' and got 54.1555 of error at last epoch, but I don't know how to interpret this value, if is good or bad.

Comment: It's useful normalize the database and then use the sigmoid or I'll lose important information?

Comment: One last thing, I said it on the question, but I forgot to update the code, I'm using keras for two outputs. Just in case it may change your understanding of my question.

Comment: Here you will find info on why sigmoid is a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976413/can-the-sigmoid-activation-function-be-used-to-solve-regression-problems-in-kera


You can interpret that by saying that this is how much your model miss the prediction on average, so here you model "miss" the correct value by +- 54.
So you need to minimise this value, the lowest, the better

Try to read on loss and metric for regression, you can also try MSE as loss and metrics, and increase your number of epochs

And two outputs don't change anything here

Comment: Try changing all your activation to linear or to relu, and look at what perform best

Comment: Hello, Thibault, I tried it and Linear was the best. If it won't bother you, I have another question. I inserted "validation_split = 0.33" in model.fit and now I have two information on output (loss and val_loss or mean_absolute_error and val_mean...), so, I don't know how to interpret these two informations. What's the most important? If I raised the epochs too much and the "val_loss" became higher than "loss", it means that my model is overfitting?
And again, thanks for the help so far, you helped me a lot.